# How to click on Toolbar element with Sahi for Test Automation?

Tags: automated-tests, toolbar, sahi

Web page contain a button with some text for example "Test". This button actually is a toolbar element. `(class ="tbButton" id="id",text="Test")` and redirects to a certain table when press on it.

When I tried to use the following click methods, the button did not react.

```
   browser.div("Test").click();
   browser.click("id");
   browser.click("");
   browser.div("id").click();
   browser.byId("id").click();
   browser.containsText(browser.byId("id"),"Test");
   browser.div("Test").in(browser.table("Generar")).click();
   browser.byXPath("//div/Test").click();
```

Could anybody suggest me an alternative methods that is able to resolve the above problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
browser.xy(browser.div("Test"), 10, 10).click();
```

This will click a little inside the div.